# HTML: Changing default cursor does not work until pointer is moved

Tags: html, css

I have an `overlayWaitDiv` defined as follows with `CSS`:

```css
#overlayWaitDiv {
    cursor:   wait;
    position: fixed;
    top:      0;
    left:     0;
    width:    100%;
    height:   100%;
    z-index:  99;
}
```

The idea is that this overlay is put on top of the other elements, taking all window space, and shows a `wait` cursor.

I am showing/hiding this by using the following `HTML`:

To display the overlay:

```html
<div id="overlayWaitDiv" style></div>
```

To hide the overlay:

```html
<div id="overlayWaitDiv" style="display: none; "></div>
```

This is working fine: the cursor is changing from normal to `wait`, and back, according to the events happening in my page. The only problem that I have is that, in order for this cursor switch to happen, the user *needs* to move the pointer.

How can I make the browser immediately change the pointer, without the need for the user to move it?

Comment: If i understand it correctly then give `display:none` with `cursor:default` and `display:block` with `cursor:wait`. reply me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is it happening only in chrome?
Did you checked in firefox?

Comment: @venkateshwar: I do not see why that would help: I have already defined the cursor style in the CSS, together with the rest of the styles needed for the overlay to do its work. Anyway, it is not easy for me to modify directly the style (I am editing the html with a framework, and I am not sure how to do certain things).

Comment: can you please show in jsfiddle site for full live page checking?

Comment: Thanks @msksiva, but that is difficult for me to do.

Answer (score 1):

put `cursor:auto;` then it will ok

Comment: How will `cursor:auto;` will solve my problems? How does `auto` know what kind of cursor I want? Where should I put it, in the CSS, in the html, ...?

Comment: Great! `cursor: default` ALWAYS gives the usual white triangle. With auto it will change depending on what you hover as the default action. So if you hover past text you'll see the text cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cursor value using java script as shown below.

```
$("#overlayWaitDiv").css("cursor","wait") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try add a class to the body tag?
Like this:

```
.waiting {
   cursor: wait;
}
```

When you need to show the waiting cursor use $("body").addClass("waiting") and $("body").removeClass("waiting") to hide.